# What is the meaning of Server :cloudflare-nginx?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I am trying to see, what is the web-server name of a particular website.

http://browserspy.dk/webserver.php

When I searched I got response as

```
Server: cloudflare-nginx
```

I know nginx and cloud-flare but I never heard a web-server named `cloudflare-nginx`.

Usually I get "nginx" as the webserver if website is powered by "nginx"

Can someone explain this Server: cloudflare-nginx means ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, Cloudflare has a custom built Nginx webserver running their services which they've renamed to cloudflare-nginx.

You can change the server header output this way:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-the-server-header-returned-by-nginx

Comment: thanks for the useful info,  i dont know why people downvote a question like this,..